# mongodb : Query array of nested string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, subquery

I have a list of objects something like

```
[
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15, type : ["hello", "world", "wassup", "yo"] } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 1515, type : ["hello", "wassup", "yo"] } ] },
   { item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 515, type : ["hello"] } ] },
   { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 3515, type : ["wassup", "yo"] } ] }
]
```

How can I query list of all warehouse in which "type" contains hello

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { $elemMatch: {type :["hello"]}}} , {_id:0})
```

returns the objects that has only hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) works in this case, try:

```
db.collection.find({ "instock.type": "hello"})
```

[MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sXW7y2dQ24t)